# Measuring the page load time

Tags: load-time

Can anyone provide an overview of what the steps are to create a tool such a Pingdom's page load time tool?  I see a lot of these out there that do essentially the same thing, but I am not sure how to go about creating a tool to do this

Comment: Something like this belongs on StackOverflow. Unfortunately they would close this as not a real question so i will not migrate this question there and just close it here. You should do some research on this first and then show your efforts there first and ask specific questions on where you are stuck.

Comment: I wasn't asking for anyone to do anything for me.  Just a broad overview of how this is done.  Obviously you have to get the page and all objects included in the source of the aforementioned page and do some calculations ... I was just looking for some guidance.  Thanks for closing this before anyone could help me out.